# Agregar palabras a una lista de palabras

Tags: array, c, archivo

intento agregar palabras a una lista de palabras definidas de esta manera:

```
char *planetas[cantPlanetas];
```

Donde cantPlanetas está definida previamente. Antes de agregar una palabra, me aseguro esta  no se repita dentro de la lista, con la siguiente función llamada busqueda:

```
//nombrePlaneta: nombre del planeta, ej: tierra
//listaPlanetas: lista de planetas, ej: [marte, jupiter]
//cant: cantidad de planetas que hay en la lista, ej: 3 (no el tamaño de listaPlanetas)
int busqueda(char * nombrePlaneta, char *listaPlanetas[], int cant){
    for(int j = 0; j <= cant; j++){
        if(strcmp(nombrePlaneta, listaPlanetas[j]) == 0){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, los datos no se agregan correctamente (estos se leen desde un archivo), si no que se sobrescribe planetas[0], el iterador que definí creo que no avanza. A continuación lo que implementé en main:

```
    int i = 0;
    while(!feof(mapa)){
        fgets(linea, 100, mapa);
        token = strtok(linea, " "); //el nombre del planeta ej: tierra
        //si i = 0, no hay planetas para comparar, por lo que se agrega directamente
        if(i == 0){
            planetas[i] = token;
            //cuando se agrega un planeta, el iterador aumenta
            i = i + 1;
        }
        // cuando i !=0, se realiza la busqueda, si se repite el planeta
        // 0 = no se repite   1 = si se repite
        else if(busqueda(token, planetas, i) == 0){
            i = i + 1;
            planetas[i] = token;
        }
    }
```

Entonces planetas[0] se sobrescribe con todos los planetas que son leídos desde el archivo. Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: Nunca inicializas el array de punteros.. por lo que veo, ese es el principal problema.